# Why is this Javascript code stopping execution in my for loop?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm learning Javascript and wrote a small program. I have a method inside my object with a for loop. Why is my console showing output when my fuel value is at 5. It should still iterate through the loop right?

```
    let car = {

    make : "Chevy",
    year : "2022",
    model : "Malibu",
    fuel : 0,
    started : false,

    start: function(){
        this.started = true;
    },

    stop: function(){
        this.started = false;
    },

    drive: function(){
        if(this.fuel > 0){
            if(this.started){
              for(let i = 0; i < this.fuel; i++){
                console.log(`Enjoying the drive in my ${this.make} --${this.model}`);
                console.log(`Fuel before deduction ${this.fuel}`);
                this.fuel = this.fuel - 1;
                console.log(`Fuel after drive = ${this.fuel}`);
              }
            }else{
                console.log(`You need to start the car to be able to drive`);
                this.stop();
            }
        }else{
            console.log("You need to fuel the car to be able to dirve");
            this.stop();
        }
    },

    addFuel: function(amount){
        this.fuel += amount;

        console.log(`Fuel Added ${this.fuel}`);
    }
};

car.drive();

car.addFuel(10);

car.drive();

car.start();

car.drive();
```

Comment: Your For loop essentially has two counters and they are just meeting in the middle when you start at 10. 

So you are counting cycles and incrementing with i, then each cycle you check if i is less then the amount of fuel remaining which goes down each cycle.

A better pattern would be to cycle down in a while loop checking a falsey value. 

while(this.fuel){
// do stuff
this.fuel--
}

Comment: Thanks Visualspark! That totally cleared my confusion.